# Eclipse deploy to Local JBOSS fails

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss

Eclipse is: 2023-12 (4.30.0)

Local JBOSS Instance is: 7.4.14

Java OpenJDK is: 11.0.17.8

This started recently, I believe after the 7.4.14 patch.  Whenever I restart the server or republish the WAR (from the Server Tab), I get the following:

08:44:54,170 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar-11.143.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myWar-11.143.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myWar-11.143.war"

...

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.ca.doj.myWar.controllers.PingService from [Module "deployment.myWar-11.143.war" from Service Module Loader]

...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.ca.doj.myWar.controllers.PingService from [Module "deployment.myWar-11.143.war" from Service Module Loader]

I can deploy through the JBOSS CLI, and I can deploy through the JBOSS Admin UI.  The problem is, I cannot debug (step through, check variable values, etc) when deployed through the CLI/UI.

At this point, my end-goal is to be able to debug my WAR, regardless of how I deploy it.

I expected a similar issue in EAP 8.0, but do not seem to have that issue using JDK17.

I am currently changing the WAR naming convention in case the dots, dashes, or underscores are the issue.

Comment: I would suggest contacting support. However, if you're building with an IDE it looks like the generated WAR is missing some things.